# Magento One Page Checkout remove twitter and facebook box

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, onepage-checkout

I want to remove the Twitter and Facebook box in OnePage Checkout, but it doesn't work.

I removed some other blocks from One Page Checkout like Newsletter and top.search, but I don't know the exact Name of the Facebook and Twitter Block.

Do you have any idea?

So I've edited and inserted in `checkout.xml` under `checkout_onepage_index`:

```
<remove name="twitter"/> 
<remove name="twitter-box"/>
<remove name="facebook"/> 
<remove name="facebook-box"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the Twitter and Facebook boxes you are talking about aren't standard Magento so my guess is this is added by the template or an extension you've installed on the shop.

Start your search with any layout files that are in the layout directory of the template you're using that are not default Magento (compare to the base template layout directory). Also look in the `local.xml` if it exists. That might also be a place where they could have been added.

Also install https://github.com/fbrnc/Aoe_TemplateHints. This extension gives you advanced template hints on the frontend that contain for example the nesting of the blocks. This might help you track down the correct layout file from where they were added.